# How can you convert a gradient to this scan-line style?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

Is there any reliable way to programatically process a grayscale gradient and end up with this lo-fi gradient style? I don't know the exact name of this style, but it's used frequently in logo design and is a sort of scan line or Venetian blinds effect.

[image: square with a black and white gradient fill and an arrow pointing to another square with a unique limited gradient style]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Illustrator

- Draw 2 paths with different stroke weights.
- Select them both
- Choose `Object > Blend > Make`
- Choose `Object > Blend > Blend Options` and adjust...

[image]

You can do this with any two paths, curved, straight or whatever...

[image]